# If Map slots started across racks then how Job Tracker process the data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

**1.** When assigning a task to Task Tracker for processing, the Job Tracker first tries to locate a Task Tracker with a free slots on the same server that has the data node containing the data (to ensure the data locality)

**2.** If it does not find this Task Tracker, it looks for a Task Tracker on another node in the same rack before it goes across the racks to locate a Task Tracker.

**Thumb rule**: Processing logic only will reach to data for processing.

Assuming that the Task tracker started on across the racks where corresponding processing data not available, So in this scenario, how processing logic (program) reaches to data,  instead of data reaches to processing logic (program)?

Comment: The task tracker spawned will ask for data from other node(s). Of course, the transfer will be limited by the bandwidth between the two racks and latency will be a factor limiting your computation speed.

Answer (score 0):

When the data are not available locally, they need to be transferred through the network. Data locality is not a rule (remote nodes cannot run the program), but a goal (always prefer the local nodes, containing the data, to run the process related with this data chunk), since transferring the data (many GBs) is more costly than traferring the code (a few KBs).